# String of length p, with m possible letters. How many strings can we form if we count all the rotations and reflections as one same string?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Take any string of length $p$, where $p$ is a prime number and $p\geq 3$, and where each character can be any element of a set of characters of length m. How many different bracelets can we make if counted all the rotations of one string ($ABA = AAB = BAA$) as one string and if we counted all reflections of the string as one ($ABC=CBA$)?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Is the $n$ in the title and the $m$ in your question supposed to be the same?

Comment: I found a recurrence relation for palindromes, but I am having issues counting how many occasions rotations and/or reflections become palindromes